# crash when attempting table view detail view in Simulator

Tags: ios, crash, tableview, xcode5

I am working on a prototype ios app in xcode 5. Tab based navigation. I have a View Controller that pushes to a Table View using a button. Once that table is populated, we are trying to generate a detail view of the table contents (with of course additional details).

Upon clicking any row of the table, I get a crash with the following info:

```
argc    int 1   1
argv    char ** 0xbfffee34  0xbfffee34
```

and

```
2014-01-01 17:25:11.430 AtlantaFire1215[10475:70b] -[UIViewController setDetailModal:]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb5a2d50
2014-01-01 17:25:11.433 AtlantaFire1215[10475:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDetailModal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb5a2d50'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I can post .h and .m files as necessary.

Updated with additional files:

TableViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController2 : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;

@end
```

TableViewController2.m

```
#import "TableViewController2.h"
#import "TableCell2.h"
#import "DetailViewController2.h"

@interface TableViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController2

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_Title = @[@"Fire Station 1",
           @"Fire Station 2",
           @"Fire Station 3",
           @"Fire Station 4",
           @"Fire Station 5",
           @"Fire Station 8",
           @"Fire Station 9",
           @"Fire Station 10",
           @"Fire Station 11",];

_Description = @[@"London, England",
                 @"Rome, Italy",
                 @"China",
                 @"Moscow, Russia",
                 @"Liberty Island, New York",
                 @"Wiltshire, England",
                 @"Agra, India",
                 @"Paris, France",
                 @"Pisa, Italy",];

_Images = @[@"atl_station_01.jpg",
            @"atl_station_02.jpg",
            @"atl_station_03.jpg",
            @"atl_station_04.jpg",
            @"atl_station_05.jpg",
            @"atl_station_08.jpg",
            @"atl_station_09.jpg",
            @"atl_station_10.jpg",
            @"atl_station_11.jpg",];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _Title.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell2";
TableCell2 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

int row = [indexPath row];

cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];;

return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
    DetailViewController2 *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];
    detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row],_Images[row]];
}
}

@end
```

I also have "DetailViewController" and "TableCell" files if necessary.

Comment: Can you show some code? If you are having trouble finding what line your project is crashing on you can turn on exception breakpoints in xcode.

Comment: Have you set the `destinationViewController` in the storyboard to be of type `DetailViewController2`? If not the storyboard will just instantiate either a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` (depending on what you dragged out from the components list), neither of these have a method called `setDetailModal:`

Comment: That was precisely it! I had not changed the custom class. Much, much appreciated.